# Server 2008 R2 constantly restarts into safe mode

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, safe-mode

I have a Server 2008 R2 virtual machine that is constantly restarting into safe mode. No prompts are given during the boot process, and if I force "Start windows normally" I *still* end up in safe mode.

I'm about to restore the server from a backup, but is there anything I can try first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Check `msconfig`](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11004157#11004157) to see if there's anything set in the boot options. Chances are there's a flag that's been set in there, as this then forms part of the "Normal" start-up routine. My server ended up having this flag set:

[image: Safe boot]

Not sure how or why the flag got checked, but un-checking it and rebooting the server made everything come back online correctly.